# router.navigate(['sample', 'route']) is changing url of page but control is not getting inside ngOnInit()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router, ngoninit

I recently updated my project from **Angular 15** to **Angular 17**. Since then I have been having this issue.

When `this.router.navigate(['sample', 'route'])` function is triggered, the URL gets changed but the page is not loaded. I debugged in the browser and saw that the control is not getting inside `ngOnInit()` function of the component called.

This functionality was working fine in previous version i.e., Angular 15

Comment: please share the code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue reproduced!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue; assuming you are injecting the Router instance using the inject method, please note that there is a difference between `Inject(Router)` and `inject(Router)`

```
import { Inject, inject } from '@angular/core';
```

You need to use the latter. i.e.

```
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
```